# How can a god justify it's own worship if it claims no moral authority?

Tags: society, religion, gods

Pantheism is worship that admits or tolerates all interpretations of deities. The human race exists throughout the multiverse, which was created and designed by God. Some are worlds that are completely run by democratic governments, while others are totalitarian empires that practice slavery. Some have cultures that lean toward matriarchies, while others are war-torn conflict zones similar to Mad-Max. All of these realms worship the same creator, but express that worship in different ways. Some see him as an all powerful, omnipotent deity, while others view God as different aspects that make up a whole, or multiple smaller deities led by a main deity.

Angels are stewards of this god who exist to keep the universe functioning. They are similar to computer programs, which are written to make the verse work in the background, but are unable to interfere directly with the inhabitants. People know of these angels and the existence of their creator as fact. These beings operate with semi-independence. They can form their own opinions on matters, but must stick to their defined task and are not capable of disobeying universal laws.The angels periodically visit these realms and communicate with humanity at certain times during a millenia, but don't enforce any particular world view. Their job is ultimately to protect the versed from threats and keep it working according to the original design (fighting off stewards from competing gods, laws of gravity, etc).

The problem I have is how these angels would interact with humanity and how they justify the worship of a God that has no rules of how to worship.  Ex: someone asks them certain questions about world views or morality, such as whether slavery or oppression of certain races or lifestyles, or modes of governing. The angels can't just come out and say "God doesn't care how you worship it, just that you worship it". This seems inauthentic and indifferent, and may push people to just not worship God at all.

Why would people devote worship to a god with no moral authority?

Comment: Why would the angels be answering these questions? And even if they did, why would they do it in a completely straight manner? Why would the angels even be talking with (essentially) random people? This seems like a big non-problem to me, as any incarnation of an angel I've seen depicted is not big on information sharing, especially when it explains exactly how their boss operates. When they do share information it's either cryptic or *very* specialised.

Comment: *"Pantheisn is worship that admits or tolerates all interpretations of deities:"* I've never heard of this interpretation. More commonly, [pantheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheism) is a belief that nature and divinity are co-extensive -- in the words of [Spinoza](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinoza), *Deus sive Natura*, God, that is, Nature. (Spinoza's thought was more complicated; Nahttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baruch_Spinozature was the manifestation of *some* of God's attributes, but only those attributes of God which manifested as Nature were perceptible by mortals.)

Comment: @AlexP : He probably means [Polytheism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polytheism)

Comment: Why does he need or care about worship?

Comment: This question seems extremely broad.  A question that begins with "how" is asking us to come up with solutions for you. A god among gods in a polytheism, or a god within a pantheistic system -- either the question is too broad or too opinion based. Can you narrow this down to a single issue?

Comment: @elementitas question has changed.

Answer (score 9):

The exact same way it is done now, formal priests, or self proclaimed 'messengers' happily do the interpreting and make up the rules in each locale or even each small group.

Anything that disagrees with them is a demon.

Comment: ...or heretics, witches, apostates, atheists....

Answer (score 6):

## Because God wills it so

God is the omnipotent creator, right?  So he doesn't need to send angels to explain his stance/apathy.  He just burns it into the soul and DNA of every person.  They know, instinctively, that God is there.  That he demands their worship.  That he doesn't care the method.  Or about Human laws or morality.

Of course they still have the free will to reject this.  And it might be a plot element in your story that a few people are born without this genetic knowledge.  And how the angels and others react to them.

## Really high persuasion or intimidation checks

You say it seems like people would not accept the answer 'God doesn't care about that' from the angels.  But that really depends on your angels.  Your divine programs could be the ultimate smooth talkers.  They explain that God watches over everyone equally and without judgement.  That he respects everyone's free will the same, even if Humans themselves don't.  The angels words are so certain, clear, and convincing, the people believe them.

Or, the angels appear as a burning pillar of solar fire.  Their mere presence lays bare a Human's soul and thoughts and secrets.  To doubt them, to question them, is to be destroyed.  They proclaim God has no opinion on the matter, and Humans accept it, because to do otherwise is to be destroyed.

Or, the angels just lie.  They are there to keep the universal order intact, right?  And God doesn't cotton to mere mortal morals.  So just give the mortals what they want.  Feed them a convincing and consistent line of BS about God's desires and rules, such that it makes it easiest for the angels to do their job and keep the universe(s) running.

Answer (score 3):

## Your angels do their jobs.

> Angels are stewards of this god who exist to keep the universe
>   functioning. They are similar to computer programs, which are written
>   to make the verse work in the background, but are unable to interfere
>   directly with the inhabitants...These beings operate with
>   semi-independence. They can form their own opinions on matters, but
>   must stick to their defined task and are not capable of disobeying
>   universal laws...***Their job is ultimately to
>   protect the versed from threats and keep it working according to the
>   original design*** (fighting off stewards from competing gods, laws of
>   gravity, etc).

They may form opinions on how close a society is to the original design or what to do about competing gods, etc.  That's not the same as saying they have human levels of ethics or morality.

Say you are a (minimalist and old fashioned) farmer.  You have flocks of animals you set out to pasture.  You check on them periodically to make sure they have enough water and that the pasture provides for their needs.  You might repair the fences and make sure that your competition (wolves, coyotes, other humans) aren't a threat.

Do you care about how the animals treat each other?  Do you care which flocks rally around a matriarch and which around a patriarch?  Do you care if some animals make other animals bring them food or force them to stand around swooshing off their flies?  Does it matter to you who gets to be first in line for the water hole?

Honestly, you probably wouldn't even notice.  If you did, you might be surprised by the complexity and variety of behavior your animals display, but any interest you have would be that of a dispassionate observer.  An anthropologist (or animal behaviorist).

As a farmer, you might be moved by the plight of a particular animal that caught your attention.  You might even intervene against bullying or slavery, what have you.  But it wouldn't mean you were out to reform the system.  Just that you sought to elevate one being (or perhaps a small group of beings) you felt something for.

In the case of the angels, if their god boss doesn't give them instructions about moral behavior in humans, it seems unlikely they'd notice or care.  If you chose to write a story about one angel (or a small group) becoming invested in human affairs, that's one thing.  But I see no reason why it would just happen.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends a lot on the existential reason for why God exists at all.

Suppose your God has nothing to do with humans at all, but in the maintenance of the balance that allows the very universe to continue to exist?

Suppose a purpose of your God is to enforce the universal application of the Laws of Physics, to ensure they are never broken? To ensure that the universe continues in a predictable, rules-based fashion? Further, suppose the purpose of God is to ensure that entropy (universal equilibrium of all energy) never occurs?

That is, God does not care what humans believe in. God is not narcissistic. The 'goal' of humans, from this perspective, is not to worship God, but to aid God in the quest to reverse entropy. That is, if there were no God, eventually the universe would degrade to complete equilibrium. However, under the direction of a God (intelligence) this degradation to equilibrium is reversed. Life, and in particular humans, concentrate energy and build. The dynamic universe is forever maintained.

So God does not care what the actual morality of human beings is. God is not interested in any concept of the 'soul' or 'goodness', only that humans continue to create, build, harness energy, and seek knowledge.

That is, God does not care whether or not humans worship God, but only that humans continue to serve the purpose of God. Consider that it is humans that drive our desire to worship God, not that God demands we worship God. That the reason for human worship of God has nothing to do with God's desire, but is entirely in our nature as intelligent beings? We worship God because  WE want to, or have a need to, worship God. The Angels, therefore, have neither the interest in nor the desire to promote worship of God. They just let humans be humans, while God carries out God's purpose.

Once you free the notion of God from the notion of the salvation of the human soul, as some being who's only desire is to be worshiped by humans, and give God a non-human-centric reason for existence, a non-human-centric goal, one that does not depend on human worship (only, perhaps, human servitude), then you allow for a completely pantheistic (using your definition) God.

That is, God does not care how you worship God, or even if you DO worship God, God only cares that you do his bidding, voluntarily and willingly or not.

In this case, your function of the angels is exactly what you stated - 'Angels are stewards of this god who exist to keep the universe functioning.'

As long as the universe continues to function (that is, entropy is never reached) they are fulfilling their mandate. Morality is not their concern, the continuation of existence of intelligence, intelect, and discovery is.